# Primeng - dialog service passing data to dialog component

Tags: typescript, components, observable, primeng

Using PrimeNg's dynamic dialogue example shows how the destination dialogue can get data and display. 
I can go through creating a service with observables to pass the data to the dialogue, but I know there are some arguments available to the dialogue service (like data) that can be passed through.
How would the dialogue retrieve the data passed through the service?

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dynamicdialog
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/dynamicdialog/dynamicdialog-config.ts
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/dynamicdialog/dialogservice.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dynamic dialog has an option in the constructor to pass data.
example,

> const ref = this.dialogService.open(MyComponent, {data : myData});

**UPDATE**

you should inject DynamicDialogService on your constructor and then you can access data which you passed on your dialog

code is here :

```
constructor( private dialogService: DynamicDialogService) {}
```

and then you can access and see all data you passed like this:

```
console.log(this.dialogSerive.data)
```

Comment: And then ow do you access `data`?

Comment: I updated this answer to latest version of primeng services approved it please❤❤

Answer (score 19):

**Inside Parent Component:**

```
this.dynamicDialogRef = this.dialogService.open(EmployeeDialogComponent, {
    header: 'View Employee Details for - ' + this.employee.name,
    width: '90%',
    contentStyle: {"min-height": "800px", "overflow": "auto"},
    baseZIndex: 10000,
    data: {employee: this.employee}
});
```

**Inside Dialog Component:**

```
export class EmployeeDialogComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(public ref: DynamicDialogRef, public config: DynamicDialogConfig) { 
     console.log("Data: " + JSON.stringify(config.data.employee));
}
ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Comment: This is an expected solution, but stops working if you accidentally have DynamicDialogConfig in providers: []

Comment: As a note, if you, like me, want to reused a component as both a dialog and a stand alone component, then you will have to make the config optional ```@Optional() private dialogConfig: DynamicDialogConfig```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. 
I deleted:

```
providers: [DialogService]
```

from component that will I passing data (dialog component)

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone coming late to the post since accepted answer not working

In the **Parent component** you send the data as follow

```js
export class DynamicDialogDemo {

    ref: DynamicDialogRef | undefined;
    
    constructor(public dialogService: DialogService) {}

    show() {
        this.ref = this.dialogService.open(ProductListDemo, { 
            // Add the data you want to send to child to data propriety 
            data: {
                id: '51gF3'
            },
            header: 'Select a Product'
        });
    }
}
```

and then in the **Child component**, you can access the data using the DynamicDialogConfig service as shown:

```
export class ProductListDemo {
  constructor(
    // Inject DynamicDialogConfig
    private dialogConfig: DynamicDialogConfig
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
  // Access data as follow
   console.log("~ this.dialogConfig.data:", this.dialogConfig.data)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That worked for me, too!

And a second hint:
Do not forget to declare the provider in NgModule:

```
import { DialogService, DynamicDialogModule } from 'primeng/dynamicdialog';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
      DialogService
  ]
})
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33552920)